# BigQuery API - totalBytesProcessed return 0

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to get the total bytes processed for my api calls.

When I launch a query the `jobs.get` always return 0 in the `totalBytesProcessed` field like :

```
        [statistics] => Array
            (
                [creationTime] => 1475161629475
                [startTime] => 1475161629592
                [endTime] => 1475161629734
                [totalBytesProcessed] => 0
                [query] => Array
                    (
                        [totalBytesProcessed] => 0
                        [totalBytesBilled] => 0
                        [cacheHit] => 1
                    )
```

On the bigquery UI I see : 5.19 KB processed for my query.

Why do my `totalBytesProcessed` return 0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out your cacheHit!
It is true  - meaning - no any bytes were actually processed  - rather result was taken from cache